# Different background positions of the same image on WordPress (header/nav bar) and how to make them same?

Tags: css, wordpress, header

I'm developing a [website](https://dylogue.com/) on WordPress and have run into a bit of a problem. Basically, my client wants the header to be like this:

[image]

Basically, when hovered over the tabs, a blue line should show under the specific tab. I inserted an image via css to do this, and it works fine.
However, when I scroll down, the theme auto changes the size(height) of the header to this:

[image]

Now, this makes it ugly as the blue line(image which i set) is now too close to the words. This is the css code I've set for the image:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HtVu9bz.png');
    background-size: 65% 2px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 50% 62%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

The objective here is to make the blue underline spacing for the scroll down version of the header navigation menu exactly the same as the un-scrolled version. I've tried lengthening the container for the scroll down version but to no avail as even though the container size for the scrolled down version is about the same as the main version, the blue underline will not budge, sticking very close to the words. So all in all, the issue is different background positions of the same image. I want to make them the same. Help would be much appreciated thx :)

Ive also tried adding this to header.php:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<script type = "text/javascript">
$("sticky-nav").hover(function () {
    if ( $("sticky-nav").hasClass( "navigation sticky offset scrolling" ) ) {
            $("sticky-nav").css("padding-bottom","7px");
    }
    else {$("sticky-nav").css("padding-bottom", "0px");}
 });
</script>
```

This was me just experimenting to increase the padding when the classes change when one scrolls down. But somehow it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it, I realized I just had to access the .navigation.sticky class aswell when scrolling instead of just navbar-nav. So I duplicated the entire css function I wrote earlier and changed the class and padding. So all in all, I now have these 2 under Additional CSS on WP:

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
background-image: url('https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HtVu9bz.png');
background-size: 65% 2px; 
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-position: 50% 62%;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}


.navigation.sticky .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{    //------>including the .sticky class
    text-decoration: none;
    background-image: url('https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HtVu9bz.png');
    background-size: 65% 2px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: 50% 62%;
    padding-bottom: 8px;    // -------> Change the padding 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution will be to use border bottom which will adjust itself based on the padding of the anchor element.

```
.menu-item.active, .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    border-bottom: 3px solid #406d96;
}
```

Comment: yep i agree, unfortunately it specifically needs to be just one space below the words and not on the border :(